Regex to contain english, greek letters, numbers, spaces and commas
I have no idea how to syntax a regex in php. I want to check/validate that certain fields of a form contain only letters (greek or latin), numbers, commas and or numbers.
So far I have this preg_match('/^[\p{Greek}\s\d 0-9a-zA-Z]+$/u', $string) but it's failing.  I have checked at this site but none of the solutions I have found worked for me.

What is failing about it? https://3v4l.org/0V47f

"none of the solutions I have found worked for me" - whenever you run into those situations, it helps us if you point out the ones you actually tried

A test string that we could test with would also be nice.

You could use ^[\p{Greek}\da-zA-Z\s,]+$). Note that a space is one type of whitespace (\s) so if you have \s in your character class the space is redundant. Similarly, you don't need both \d and 0-9. Demo

To create a regex in PHP that validates a string containing only Greek or Latin letters, numbers, and commas, you can modify your pattern slightly. Here is an improved version of your regex pattern:
<?php
preg_match('/^[\p{Greek}a-zA-Z0-9, ]+$/u', $string);
?>

This pattern includes:
\p{Greek}: matches any Greek character.
a-zA-Z: matches any Latin letter.
0-9: matches any digit.
,: matches a comma.
A space character to allow spaces between words or numbers.
Here's how you can use this regex pattern in a PHP function to validate your string:
<?php
function validateString($string) {
    return preg_match('/^[\p{Greek}a-zA-Z0-9, ]+$/u', $string);
}

$string = "καλως ΗΡΘΑΤΕ";

if (validateString($string)) {
    echo "The string is valid.";
} else {
    echo "The string is invalid.";
}
?>

